# How to get a recordid from OrientDB on insert?

Tags: insert, nosql, orientdb

OrientDB question...

Does anyone know how I can get the recordId after an insert:

```
db.save(person)
```

I tried below on the Person POJO:

```
@Id
private Object id;
```

but the id field was null after the save. I've googled and googled to no avail. I just need to insert an object, then get the recordid that orientdb generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work using ODocuments instead of POJOs (which works for my project). Code sample:

```
    ODatabaseDocumentTx db  = null;
    ODocument           doc = null;

    db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("local:" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/testDB");
    db.create();
    doc = new ODocument("Person");
    doc.field("name", "Peter");
    doc.save();
    String rid = doc.getIdentity().toString();
    List<ODocument> results = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("select from " + rid));
    for (ODocument aDoc : results) {
        System.out.println(aDoc.field("name"));
    }
    db.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Define field in pojo:

```
@Id
private Object rid;

public Object getRid() {
    return rid;
}
```

When save:

```
YourClass proxy = db.save(yourClassInstance);
Object rid = proxy.getRid();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just simple here is the code:

```
//insertquery will be the sql statement you want to insert

    ODocument result=db.command(new OCommandSQL(insertquery)).execute();

    System.out.println(result.field("@rid"));
```

Comment: Also it worths to mention, that if you are in the middle of a transaction, the `result.field("@rid")` won't return the real RecordID (it returns something like #-1:-2). Although  after the transaction has been committed, it will return the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can make use of getRecordByUserObject() of OObjectDatabaseTx,

```
OObjectDatabaseTx db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("local:" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/testDB");

ODocument oDocument = db.getRecordByUserObject( person, true );
oDocument.save();

String rid = oDocument.getIdentity().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have access to your proxy object from the save, you can totally do a cool cast on it to get the underlying ODocument object which has a record ID (Identity).

```
Person proxyPerson = db.save(person);

ODocument oDocument = ((OObjectProxyMethodHandler)((ProxyObject)proxyPerson).getHandler()).getDoc();
person.setId(oDocument.getIdentity().toString());
```

Comment: This is useful if you can't use JPA annotations for whatever reason.